# GSON custom serializer for Map with Enum keys

Tags: json, spring, serialization, gson

The object I am serializing contains a map which has keys that are Enums. Those Enums have a variable. When I serialize it with GSON, I would like for the resulting JSON to have the Enum variable instead of the default Enum name. I have tried creating a custom serializer and registering it, but it isn't doing the trick. Here is my code.

The controller:

```
@Controller
public class CheckoutClientController {

@Autowired
private Gson gson;
@Autowired
private RequestHelper requestHelper;
@Autowired
private SettingsReader settingsReader;

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(CheckoutConfigurationDto.class, new JsonDeserializerPropertyEditor<CheckoutConfigurationDto>(gson, CheckoutConfigurationDto.class));
}

/**
 * Handles requests to the Checkout Client page, which is the outer wrapper that includes the white label checkout (WLC) iframe. Sets up the configuration
 * data needed to pass to the WLC server.
 * 
 * @return the model and view
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkout/checkout-client.ep", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showPage(HttpServletRequest request) {
    CheckoutClientConfigurationDto checkoutClientConfig = new CheckoutClientConfigurationDto();

    StringBuilder host = new StringBuilder();
    host.append(request.getScheme()).append("://");
    host.append(request.getServerName());
    host.append(":").append(request.getServerPort());

    checkoutClientConfig.setWlcHost(host.toString());
    checkoutClientConfig.setClientId("clientId");
    checkoutClientConfig.setAppId("appId");
    checkoutClientConfig.setId("wlc-widget");

    Map<CheckoutClientConfigurationOption, Boolean> options = checkoutClientConfig.getOptions();

    options.put(CheckoutClientConfigurationOption.SHOW_ORDER_CONFIRMATION,
            Boolean.valueOf(this.settingsReader.getSettingValue(SettingsConstants.SHOW_ORDER_CONFIRMATION).getValue()));
    options.put(CheckoutClientConfigurationOption.REMOVE_CART_ITEMS,
            Boolean.valueOf(this.settingsReader.getSettingValue(SettingsConstants.REMOVE_CART_ITEMS).getValue()));

    return new ModelAndView(ViewConstants.CHECKOUT_CLIENT_TEMPLATE_PATH, "checkoutClientConfig", gson.toJson(checkoutClientConfig));
}
}
```

CheckoutClientConfigurationDto (minus all the boilerplate getters/setters):

```
public class CheckoutClientConfigurationDto implements Dto {

private String wlcHost;

private String clientId;

private String appId;

private String id;

private Map<CheckoutClientConfigurationOption, Boolean> options;

public CheckoutClientConfigurationDto() {
    products = new ArrayList<ProductDto>();
    options = new HashMap<CheckoutClientConfigurationOption, Boolean>();
}

public Map<CheckoutClientConfigurationOption, Boolean> getOptions() {
    return options;
}

public void setOptions(final Map<CheckoutClientConfigurationOption, Boolean> options) {
    this.options = options;
}
}
```

CheckoutClientConfigurationOption:

```
public enum CheckoutClientConfigurationOption {

SHOW_SAVED_ADDRESSES("showSavedAddresses", true),
SHOW_CART_SUMMARY("showCartSummary", true),
REMOVE_CART_ITEMS("removeCartItems", true),
SHOW_DISCOUNT_FIELD("showDiscountField", true),
SHOW_VAT_CODE("showVatCode", true),
SHOW_ORDER_CONFIRMATION("showOrderConfirmation", true),
SHOW_CANCEL_BUTTON("showCancelButton", false),
SINGLE_PAGE_CHECKOUT("singlePageCheckout", false),
SEND_ORDER_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL("sendOrderConfirmationEmail", true),
SEND_SHIPPING_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL("sendShippingConfirmationEmail", true);

private String optionName;

private boolean defaultValue;

private CheckoutClientConfigurationOption(final String optionName, final boolean defaultValue) {
    this.optionName = optionName;
    this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
}

public boolean getDefautValue() {
    return defaultValue;
}

public String getOptionName() {
    return optionName;
}
}
```

My custom GSON serializer:

```
public class CheckoutClientConfigurationOptionGsonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<CheckoutClientConfigurationOption> {

@Override
public JsonElement serialize(CheckoutClientConfigurationOption src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    return new JsonPrimitive(src.getOptionName());
}

}
```

My custom GSON Configurer:

```
public class GsonConfigurer {

private Map<Class<?>, Object> typeAdapterMap;

public Gson create() {
    final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

    for (final Entry<Class<?>, Object> typeAdapterMapping : typeAdapterMap.entrySet()) {
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(typeAdapterMapping.getKey(), typeAdapterMapping.getValue());
    }

    return gsonBuilder.create();
}

protected Map<Class<?>, Object> getTypeAdapterMap() {
    return typeAdapterMap;
}

public void setTypeAdapterMap(final Map<Class<?>, Object> typeAdapterMap) {
    this.typeAdapterMap = typeAdapterMap;
}

}
```

The XML:

```
<bean id="gsonConfigurer" class="com.sfweb.gson.GsonConfigurer">
    <property name="typeAdapterMap">
        <util:map key-type="java.lang.Class">
            <entry key="com.sfweb.dto.CheckoutConfigurationOption">
                <bean class="com.sfweb.dto.deserializer.CheckoutConfigurationOptionGsonDeserializer" />
            </entry>
            <entry key="com.sfweb.dto.CheckoutClientConfigurationOption">
                <bean class="com.sfweb.dto.serializer.CheckoutClientConfigurationOptionGsonSerializer" />
            </entry>
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="com.google.gson.Gson" factory-bean="gsonConfigurer" factory-method="create" />
```

I also have a custom deserializer, as you can see in the XML. That one works with no problems. I ran in debug mode and the line in CheckoutClientConfigurationOptionGsonSerializer is never hit. I checked that the gson object that I call toJson() on has the custom serializer in it. So I'm not sure what the problem is. I have a feeling I'm just missing one piece.

I am wanting the resulting JSON to say "showSavedAddresses", but instead it is saying "SHOW_SAVED_ADDRESSES". Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. My guess would be that, since keys on JS objects need to ultimately be strings, it's simply running `value.toString()` instead of the preferred `value.toJsonAndRunCustomSerializer().toString()`.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the documentation on [GsonBuilder#enableComplexMapKeySerialization](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization) I see this:

> The default implementation of map serialization uses toString() on the key

So it doesn't run your `TypeAdapter` on map keys by default. I tried simply calling this method and got my enums to show up as numeric strings.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be well served to study [TypeAdapterFactory's documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html). It includes an example that formats enums as lowercase; you can modify this to your own needs.

```
public class LowercaseEnumTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapter.Factory {
  public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
    Class<T> rawType = (Class<T>) type.getRawType();
    if (!rawType.isEnum()) {
      return null;
    }

    final Map<String, T> lowercaseToConstant = new HashMap<String, T>();
    for (T constant : rawType.getEnumConstants()) {
      lowercaseToConstant.put(toLowercase(constant), constant);
    }

    return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
      public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
          out.nullValue();
        } else {
          out.value(toLowercase(value));
        }
      }

      public T read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
          reader.nextNull();
          return null;
        } else {
          return lowercaseToConstant.get(reader.nextString());
        }
      }
    };
  }

  private String toLowercase(Object o) {
    return o.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.US);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this route and I pretty much got the same result. I'm finding that the problem is the fact that my enums are embedded as keys of my map. It serializes the enum as lowercase with no problem if I have it as a single variable in my DTO, but when I use it as a key to the map, it doesn't call my custom serializer or my custom type adapter.